# Shape mismatch when load model in nodejs with @tensorflow/tfjs-node (it's OK in browser with same code)

Tags: node.js, tensorflow

I have trained a tf.Sequential model and deployed this model to a remote server, it's ok to load the deployed model in browser, but when if i try to load the deployed model from nodejs environment, A strange shape mismatch error occur:

*Error: Based on the provided shape, [98,50], the tensor should have 4900 values but has 86*

code:

```js
// 
const model = 'http://some-deployed-pretrained-model-in-browser.com/model.json';

// In browser: run with web app,
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

(async () => {
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(model);
    model.summary(); // it works.
})();

// In nodejs, (run with node, just the same js code)
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node';

(async () => {
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(model); // UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Based on the provided shape, [98,50], the tensor should have 4900 values but has 86
    model.summary(); // 
})();
```

But it's OK to load from local file system:

```js
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node';

// ..., just the same url, but downloaded to local file system
axios.get(model, { responseType: 'stream' }).then(res => res.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('model.json')));
// a crafted path to the 'weights.bin' file
axios.get(modelBin, { responseType: 'stream' }).then(res => res.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('model.weights.bin')));
// ...
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('file://model.json');
model.summary(); // it works.
```

My node application is running in a docker env, so I don't want to download the model files to local filesystem.

Anything I can do to make it works without downloading the model ?

I was using the latest @tensorflow/tfjs and @tensorflow/tfjs-node package (^1.7.2 for tfjs, ^1.7.3 for tfjs-node)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by create my own customized IOHandler, still don't understand why node_http handler doesn't work.

```js
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import axios from 'axios';
import url from 'url';

/**
 * Convert a Buffer or an Array of Buffers to an ArrayBuffer.
 *
 * If the input is an Array of Buffers, they will be concatenated in the
 * specified order to form the output ArrayBuffer.
 */
export function toArrayBuffer(buf: Buffer | Buffer[]): ArrayBuffer {
  if (Array.isArray(buf)) {
    // An Array of Buffers.
    let totalLength = 0;
    for (const buffer of buf) {
      totalLength += buffer.length;
    }

    const ab = new ArrayBuffer(totalLength);
    const view = new Uint8Array(ab);
    let pos = 0;
    for (const buffer of buf) {
      pos += buffer.copy(view, pos);
    }
    return ab;
  }
  // A single Buffer. Return a copy of the underlying ArrayBuffer slice.
  return buf.buffer.slice(buf.byteOffset, buf.byteOffset + buf.byteLength);
}

export class FleuralModelLoader implements tf.io.IOHandler {

  readonly MODEL_JSON_FILENAME = 'model.json';

  readonly WEIGHTS_BINARY_FILENAME = 'weights.bin';

  constructor(public path: string) {}

  async save(): Promise<tf.io.SaveResult> {
    throw new Error('save is not implemented');
  }

  async load(): Promise<tf.io.ModelArtifacts> {
    return this.loadJSONModel();
  }

  protected async loadJSONModel(): Promise<tf.io.ModelArtifacts> {
    const path = this.path as string;

    // `path` can be either a directory or a file. If it is a file, assume
    // it is model.json file.
    const modelJSON = await axios.get(path).then((res) => res.data);

    const modelArtifacts: tf.io.ModelArtifacts = {
      modelTopology: modelJSON.modelTopology,
      format: modelJSON.format,
      generatedBy: modelJSON.generatedBy,
      convertedBy: modelJSON.convertedBy,
    };
    if (modelJSON.weightsManifest != null) {
      const [weightSpecs, weightData] = await this.loadWeights(modelJSON.weightsManifest, path);
      modelArtifacts.weightSpecs = weightSpecs;
      modelArtifacts.weightData = weightData;
    }
    if (modelJSON.trainingConfig != null) {
      modelArtifacts.trainingConfig = modelJSON.trainingConfig;
    }
    if (modelJSON.userDefinedMetadata != null) {
      modelArtifacts.userDefinedMetadata = modelJSON.userDefinedMetadata;
    }
    return modelArtifacts;
  }

  private async loadWeights(
    weightsManifest: tf.io.WeightsManifestConfig,
    path: string,
  ): Promise<[tf.io.WeightsManifestEntry[], ArrayBuffer]> {
    const buffers: Buffer[] = [];
    const weightSpecs: tf.io.WeightsManifestEntry[] = [];
    for (const group of weightsManifest) {
      for (const p of group.paths) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
        const buffer = await axios.get(url.resolve(path, p), { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then((res) => res.data);
        buffers.push(buffer);
      }
      weightSpecs.push(...group.weights);
    }
    return [weightSpecs, toArrayBuffer(buffers)];
  }
}
```

This is modified from the source code of the fs handler, i change the file read codes to axios http requests and remove all the existence checks